# Why function as array item in php class doesn't work

Tags: php, arrays, class, function

For example, I have such a code:

```
<?php
$A = array(
    'echoSmth' => function(){ 
        echo 'Smth';
    }
);

$A['echoSmth']();  // 'Smth'
?>
```

It works fine!
But If $A is not just a variable, but a Class method - than this doesn't work:

```
<?php

class AA {

    public $A = array(
        'echoSmth' => function(){ // Parse Error here!
            echo 'Smth';
        }
    );

}

// Fixed call:
$t = new AA();
$t->A['echoSmth']();
// no matter what call, because error occurs early - in describing of class

?>
```

Why doesn't it work?
It displays:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION`

P.S. Sorry, I've made some mistakes in the way I call the method, I was in hurry. But there's no matter how I call. Error ocurrs even if I just declare class, without calling

Comment: try $t->a['echoSmth'](); without the dollar sign

Comment: @usoban: a in uppercase.

Comment: @marcel right, I was looking at the last line, where a is lowercase. my bad :)

Comment: Yes, I had mistakes in call of function. But I forgot to say, that error occurs when describing class. Without calling it occurs too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you can't have anything dynamic when defining a class member, you can however set it dynamically as below. So basically, you can't do it for the same reason that you can't do this: `public $A = functionname();`

Also, your call signature was incorrect, I've fixed it in my example.

```
<?php
class AA {
    public $A = array();

    public function __construct() {
        $a = function() {
            echo 'Smth';
        };
        $this->A['echoSmth'] = $a;
    }
}

$t = new AA();
$t->A['echoSmth']();
```

Alternatively, you could define the whole array within `__construct()`, containing the method (so basically shift your code).

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work. Not sure why direct declaration is not permitted though.

```
class AA {
    var $A;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->A = array(
            'echoSmth' => function(){
                echo 'Smth';
            }
        );
    }
}

$t = new AA();
$t->A['echoSmth']();
```

EDIT: I also saw and corrected `$t->$a` first, but I needed to move the declaration as well to make it work.

Comment: He has an error, he's using $t->$a instead of $t->a. You got the code right, the OP didn't. There's no php issue here, just a simple mistake when accessing the member.

Comment: @Michael Incorrect, there's a parse error for defining a closure when defining the value of $A (But yes that was an error).

Comment: That one is also true rudi, I skimmed trough the class and assumed he did make sure he hasn't got parse errors - apparently, you can't trust anyone these days, thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: @Michael Yes when I first looked it over I was thinking the same thing, but the reasoning is as defined in my answer! :-)

Comment: @Michael J.V. Just that change (or even removing the last row) still gives the error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION`.

Comment: @Gustav Larsson. So, it can be done only in __construct, isn't it?

Comment: Innuendo - your original code contained several parse errors. What you are trying to achieve CAN be done and was done. Your code also contained wrong reference to the object member. There are examples posted that work, you should just read one of them and try to amend your own parse errors.

Comment: @Michael J.V.  Error what I was trying to fix wasn't related with errors, that were in my code ($t->$a instead of $t->A). I fixed them, but there is another error - parse error. Exactly this parse error is bothering me. I see, that in __construct function it works fine. Is it possible to make it work without filling this array in __construct method?

Comment: @Innuendo You can do it in another method. The only thing you can't do (as in my answer) is assign dynamically to a class member variable. Any dynamic assignments must be done at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

well , it kinda works ...

```
<?php

    class Bleh
    {

        public $f = array();

        public function register( $name , $func )
        {

            $this->f[ $name ] =  $func;

        }

    }   


    $foo = new Bleh;
    $foo->register( 'bar' , function(){ echo 'foobar'; } );

    $foo->f['bar']();

?>
```