# Worpdress - How to keep custom variables?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to keep some theme variables in config class. But I get an error when tring to use `esc_html__( 'Facebook' )` function.

What is the best way to store custom variable in class? And why I cannot use esc_html__ function?

```
class config
{
    static $vConfig = array(        
        'colors' => array(
            'body' => '#f6f6f6'
        ),
        'social' => array(
            'facebook' => esc_html__( 'Facebook' )
        )
    );  
}
```

Here is an error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')' in ...
```

Comment: You should add the error you're getting as well.

Comment: You sure the line referenced in the error belongs to that piece of code? To me the code seems valid syntax wise.

Comment: I am sure. When I change "esc_html__( 'Facebook' )" to something else for e.g. "test", the error disappears.

Comment: I had a look around and found these two links, I think they can explain the behavior here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5842612/1169798 and http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static.properties

Comment: PS: the problem is not the `esc_html__()` function, but can be reproduced with any function call at that position.